# Play Framework: Cannot write findById function using SLICK

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am trying to write a findById(pk: Long) and an update() function for a model I have created using SLICK. However in my findById method it says returns a compilation error of "value filter is not a member of object models.About" and highlights the model name About in the findById method.

```
    package models

//import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver._


case class About(
    id:Option[Long],
    name: String, 
    subheading: String, 
    about: String
)

object About extends Table[About]("about"){
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O AutoInc) 
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def subheading = column[String]("subheading")
    def about = column[String]("about")

    def * = id.? ~ name ~ subheading ~ about <> (About.apply _, About.unapply _)

    def update(id: Long, about: About)(implicit session: Session) = findById(id).update(about)

    def findById(pk: Long) =
        for (a <- About if a.id === pk) yield a

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your findById with:

```
def findById(pk: Long) =
    for (a <- Query(About) if a.id === pk) yield a
```

Maybe you will have to add `import simple._` under the driver import.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked perfectly. Do you know why in most examples the Query() isn't needed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use this method too:

```
def findById(id: Int) = {
    byId(id).list.headOption
}
```

and `import scala.slick.jdbc.{ GetResult, StaticQuery }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply and alternative answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.  I've seen this used in other places but can't seem to work out why not for me.